# Angular Forms reactive - cross-control validation

Tags: angular, angular-forms, custom-validators

I'm working on a validator for a reactive form in angular 5, and having difficulty setting a validator that is based on the value of another input.

The form looks something like this:

```
let myRules = new FormArray([]);
myRules.push(this.newRuleFormGroup(1, 'period', 1));

this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      'name': new FormControl(name, [Validators.required, this.validate_usedName.bind(this)]), // V: must not exist already
      'icon': new FormControl(icon, [Validators.required]), // has default
      'rules': myRules
    })
```

'rules' is a `FormArray`, and I push new `FormGroup`s from the template using:

```
newRuleFormGroup = (amount: number, period: string, repAmount: number = 1) => {
    return new FormGroup({
      'amount': new FormControl(amount, [Validators.required]),
      'type': new FormControl(period, [Validators.required]),
      'repAmount': new FormControl(repAmount, [this.validate_repAmount.bind(this)])
    })
  }
```

`repAmount` is only required when `type == "period"`. In the validator for `repAmount`, I am trying to reach the parent `FormGroup` and try to get the value of his child `'type'` control. Something like this:

```
validate_repAmount(control:FormControl): {[s:string]: boolean}{
  let type = control.parent.get('type');// Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
  let controlValue = control.value;
  console.log(control.parent); // returns the parent FormGroup object
  if(type.value == 'period' && (controlValue != '' || controlValue>0)) {
      return {'repAmountMissing':true};
  }
    return null;
  }
```

But I keep getting an error saying `Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. If I try to `console.log(control.parent)`, i get the FormGroup object as expected, but I can't seem to access it in any way using its properties.

Could anyone suggest a way to access the 'type' value in  the same group for the validator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should wrap your code as below:

```
if (parent) { YOUR_VALIDATION_GOES_HERE }
```

I had the same issue once and this is how I solved it.

**Update:** You can try something like this.

```
validate_repAmount(control: FormControl): { [s: string]: boolean } {
const parent = control.parent;
if (parent) {
    let type = parent.get('type');
    let controlValue = control.value;
    if (type.value == 'period' && (controlValue != '' || controlValue > 0)) {
        return { 'repAmountMissing': true };
    }
}

return null;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how I would implement this?

Comment: are you able to explain why this works only after checking `parent`?

Comment: As I can see, this function getting trigger even before the form creation. So at that time control.parent return null. So you can't get control out from null parent. That's the reason for the error. We can solve it by introducing null check. :)

Answer (score 3):

Any time you want to do some cross validations, you should move the validation login to the ancestor control. In this case it would be your `FormGroup`.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ValidatorFn, FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

const validator: ValidatorFn = (fg: FormGroup) => {
  const rep = fg.get('repAmount');
  const type = fg.get('type');

  const required = type.value === 'period' ? Validators.required(rep) : null;

  return required ? required: null;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="type" placeholder="type">
   <input formControlName="repAmount" placeholder="repAmount" >
  </form>

   {{ form.valid }}
  `,
  styles: [`
  input: { width: 100% }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      repAmount: [null],
      type: [null]
    }, { validator });

   const repCtrl = this.form.get('repAmount')

    this.form.statusChanges.pipe(
      map(status => status === 'INVALID'),
      map(invalid => invalid ? { err: true } : null)
    ).subscribe(err => repCtrl.setErrors(err, { emitEvent: false }))
  }
}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-cross-vaildation-example-1)

Comment: Thank you! That works to make the group invalid when the conditions aren't met. However it isn't making the repAmount control invalid on it's own (which is useful for styling).

Comment: check out my edit, you can set the error by subscribing to the parent error `statusChanges` stream

Comment: This was a very useful solution. However the solution from @Rukshan was much more accurate to what I needed, without the need to pipe and subscribe the status changes.

Comment: @TomaszKula What happens if you need multiple validators on a form instead of just a single one? How can I get an array returned with all errors not just the last one?